# NSPredicate filter to-Many with child object property

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I have what I thought was a simple problem. I am attempting to filter some core data where I have a Parent object which has a to-many relationship with a child object and that child object has a string id. I want to get all the parent objects where no child object has a specific id.

I have tried `!(ANY... LIKE)` as well as `!(ANY..==)` and `NONE` with like and == and `ALL children.id != otherid`

My querying looks like:

```
NSFetchRequest* fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Parent"];

NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NONE children.id LIKE %@",otherID];
[fetchRequest setPredicate: predicate];
NSError* error;
NSArray* allParents = [[DataManager context] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
//sanity check the predicate
for (Parent* p in allParents) {
    for (Child* c in p.children) {
        if([c.id isEqualToString:otherID]){
            NSLog(@"PREDICATE FAIL!");
        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something with NSPredicate? Is this type of filtering allowed for CoreData? Better solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Core Data NSPredicate with to-Many Relationship](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722930/core-data-nspredicate-with-to-many-relationship) - Summary: That is a Core Data bug and you can use a SUBQUERY as a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a similar question although not easily apparent. It turns out the answer is the tricky SUBQUERY. Here is what led me on the chase:

[NSPredicate Aggregate Operations with NONE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14471910/nspredicate-aggregate-operations-with-none)

and an more open explanation about SUBQUERY here:

http://funwithobjc.tumblr.com/post/2726166818/what-the-heck-is-subquery

The resulting predicate is:

```
//in children get a $child and group all the $child objects together
//where the ids match, if that groups count is 0 we know 
//the parent has no child with that id
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
   @"SUBQUERY(children, $child, $child.id == %@).@count == 0",objectId];
```