# NSPredicate to find missing optional to-many attribute

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

CoreData structure is something like this:

```
Item with to-many relationship (optional)
    to Details
        with Status attribute (optional)
```

Need to find all items, which have certain status - or status that is missing. By experimenting this was the only code I got fetching me all items, where status is 0 (zero, default and minimum value).

```
+ (NSPredicate *)itemStatusCleanPredicate {
    return [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
        @"ANY details.status IN %@", @[@(StatusDefault)]]; // NSNumber 0 (zero)
};
```

How to fetch ALSO items, where the optional status is completely missing? So either status is zero or status is missing?

Even thought relationship is optional, in practise it's always been there when this code is run. However status attribute can really be missing because a) it didn't exist in previous app database versions and b) it's only created when item status changes in certain details thus having it missing it totally locigal from user perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, which seems to work:

```
+ (NSPredicate *)itemStatusCleanPredicate {
    return [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
    @"(ANY details.status.@count == 0) OR (ANY details.status IN %@)",
        @[@(StatusDefault)]]; // NSNumber 0 (zero)
};
```

Haven't found much CoreData documentation, so I'm just guessing that using "@count" will tell me whether attribute exists or not. At least I get results I wanted to have :)

Btw this QA had good tips: ["NSPredicate filter to-many with child object property"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20235878/113079)