# Can't fetch entities with many-to-many relationship

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have many-to-many relationship and try to get users which doesn't contain in relationship some category with id. When I try to fetch I get all users if user contain more than one category.

I trying to fetch with this predicate[image]

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you want to do but it does look like you need to use a subquery, see for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44347626/core-data-fetch-predicate-not-contain

Comment: @JoakimDanielson it doesn't answer what I need, but the question you sent contains the link to another question with answer for my case. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Great, I’ll close this one then